# $a_{1}=a_{2}=1$ and $ a_{n}=\tfrac{1}{2} (a_{n-1}+\tfrac{2}{a_{n-2}}) $ for $n\geq 3$. Then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $1\leq a_{n} \leq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

- Let $a_{n}$ be the sequence satisfying $a_{1}=a_{2}=1$ and $ a_{n}=\tfrac{1}{2} (a_{n-1}+\tfrac{2}{a_{n-2}}) $ for $n\geq 3$. Then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $1\leq a_{n} \leq 2$

For $n=3$, then we have $1\leq a_n\leq 2.$

Now assume for $n$ holds. Show for $n+1$ holds.

So

$$ a_{n+1}=\tfrac{1}{2} (a_{n}+\tfrac{2}{a_{n-1}}) $$

**Then, what should I do now?**

Comment: Induction is the right approach. What can you say about the two terms in your sum with the induction hypothesis?

Comment: It can be proved with induction. Could you post your "induction" attempt?

Comment: Edited question. I added my proof-trying

Comment: @user113102 Edited question. I added my proof-trying

Comment: @DrinkingDonuts Edited question. I added my proof-trying

Comment: It seems like the sequence for finding $\sqrt{2}$ using Newton method.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to proof this: $$$$ $$a_n\gt 1\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N_{>2}$$ $$$$ $$a_n>a_{n-2}$$ $$$$ $$ a_n\cdot a_{n+1}\to 2\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty$$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva If we prove this, then how can I conclude that? I couldn't understand your claim.

Comment: Well, if we have two strictly increasing sequences $a_1,a_3,a_5,\ldots$ and $a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots$ where all elements are $\ge 1$ and the product of two consecutive elements (one from each sequence) approaches $2$, then, can one of the elements be $\ge 2$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $1\le a_k\le 2$ for all $k<n.$ Then $\frac12(a_{n-1}+\frac2{a_{n-2}})\leq \frac12(2+2/1)=2$  and similarly $\frac12(a_{n-1}+\frac2{a_{n-2}})\ge \frac12(1+2/2)=1$ because $1\leq a_k\leq 2$ for all $ k\le n-1.$

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer

Comment: How did you get $\frac12(a_{n-1}+\frac2{a_{n-2}})\leq \frac12(2+2/1)=2$ and $\frac12(a_{n-1}+\frac2{a_{n-2}})\ge \frac12(1+2/2)=1$?

Comment: $a_{n-2}\geq 1\implies 2/a_{n-2}\leq 2$ and $a_{n-1}\leq 2.$ And the other inequality follows similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Prove the following $\forall n\ge 1$ by induction: $a_n,\,a_{n+1}\in[1,\,2]$. We know the $n=1$ case; for the inductive step, we only need show $a_k,\,a_{k+1}\in[1,\,2]\implies a_{k+2}\in[1,\,2]$. Indeed, $2a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+\frac{2}{a_k}$, each term $\in[1,\,2]$.

Comment: We now for $n=3$, no $n=1$.

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet I've shifted the indices on your recursion. From $a_1,\,a_2$, which are the subject of the $n-=1$ case in my proof, we get $a_3$, which is addressed in the $n=2$ case reached by the inductive step.

Comment: How can I show $a_k,\,a_{k+1}\in[1,\,2]\implies a_{k+2}\in[1,\,2]$? Can you help?

Comment: I told you: $a_{k+1},\,2/a_k$ are each in this range, as is their average $a_{k+2}$.