# Let $a_n$ be a sequence satisfying $a_1 = a_2 = 1$, and $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{a_{n-2}})$ for $n \ge 3$. Prove that $1\le a_n\le 2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing, induction

> **Problem.** Let $a_n$ be a sequence satisfying
> $$ a_1 = a_2 = 1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad a_n = \frac{1}{2}\left( a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{a_{n-2}} \right) $$
> for $n \ge 3$. Prove that $ 1\le a_n \le 2 $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**What I did:**

*Base Case:* If $n = k = 3$,

$$a_3 = \frac{1}{2} \left( a_{2} + \frac{2}{a_{1}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{2}{1}\right) = 1.5, $$

which is $\ge 1$ and $\le 2$. Therefore base case is true.

*Inductive Step:* Assume $1 \le a_n \le 2$ for $n = k \geq 3$. Consider $n = k + 1$.

$$ 1 \le a_{k+1} \le 2
\implies 1 \le \frac{1}{2}\left(a_{k} + \frac{2}{a_{k-1}}\right) \le 2$$

From here, I am stuck, unsure what to do next.
I understand strong induction is needed here, but I don't know how exactly to implement it.

---

Apologies for poor $\LaTeX$ formatting, it's my first time.

Comment: *Hint.* Consider a strong induction by proving a statement of the form $$\text{[$1 \le a_k \le 2$ for all $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$] holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}$$ The point is that, when proving $1 \leq a_{n+1} \leq 2$, you will need both $1 \leq a_n \leq 2$ and $1 \leq a_{n-1} \leq 2$. The above form of the statement will allow you to borrow both inequalities from the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3207331/42969

Comment: @MartinR Just curious, how did you find the duplicate? I googled the question originally and I couldn't find that post, so how did you find it?

Comment: Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_n%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cleft(%20a_%7Bn-1%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Ba_%7Bn-2%7D%7D%20%5Cright)%24) – see also [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).

Comment: Thank you that is extremely helpful

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a very good question. According to your question $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-1+\frac{2}{a_n-2})$ for $n\geq3$ . And $a_1=a_2=1$ . Now try to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$ . Now $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$$ = $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}(a_n-1+\frac{2}{a_n-2})$$. So, $a_\infty=\frac{a_\infty}{2}+\frac{1}{a_\infty}$ . So, $(a_\infty)^{2}=2$ . So, $a_\infty=\sqrt{2}$ . Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\sqrt{2}$$ . Why I took $+\sqrt{2}$ and not $-\sqrt{2}$ because $a_n$ will lie between $[1,2]$ for every $n\geq3$ . So, your condition is proved i.e. $1\leq a_n\leq2$ .

Comment: We haven't learnt about limits. This wouldn't be applicable to my specific question because I asked to solve it using induction & strong induction

Comment: -1 The limit of the sequence being $ \sqrt{2}$, doesn't mean that each term will be in the range of $[1, 2]$. EG The sequence $0, 0, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}, \ldots$.

Comment: Actually your question will become very easy using the theory of limits.

Comment: That's why I applied the concept of limits.